# Representing nested JSON as nodes in neo4j (SDN)

Tags: java, json, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Here is my json

```
{
    "curriculum": {
        "default_language_id": 1,
        "default_language_code": "en",
        "created_by": 1,
        "depth_order": 0,
        "layer_count": 3,
        "rack_name_meta_info": [
            {
                "name": {
                    "en": "ICSE",
                    "hi": "आईसीएसई"
                },
                "icon": "icon/99.png",
                "color": "#23bd99"
            }
        ],
        "ICSE": [
            {
                "default_language_id": 1,
                "default_language_code": "en",
                "depth_order": 0,
                "rack_name_meta_info": [
                    {
                        "name": {
                            "en": "X",
                            "hi": "भदसवां"
                        },
                        "icon": "icon/99.png",
                        "color": "#23bd99"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to represent this JSON as set of different nodes in Neo4j.

However the nested components are not being displayed.

The ***rack_name_metainfo*** has a field of ***ICSE*** which further opens up to various other fields.

I'm not able to display such a nested relationship in Graph.

In my model class in which type do I keep the ***rack_name_meta_info*** ?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Hey one probable solution is like below

```
class curriculum{
   @Realtionship("HAS_RACK_INFOS")
   private List<RackName> rack_name_metainfoList;
}

class RackName{
    @Realtionship("HAS_BOARDS")
    private List<Boards> boards; //ICSE
}
```

A Curriculam has a List of RanckName and further RackName has List of Boards.

Comment: rack_name_metainfo has a field called ICSE which opens up to be a board.
Adding relationships isn't guaranteeing that the same Board will be matched with

Comment: "en": "ICSE",  -->  "ICSE": [   Are you trying to say this is referring to this one

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm expecting.